# How to inject HTML code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I'm trying to put HTML objects in the view using JavaScript. Is this possible? I'm looking for something like the following:

```
<script>
 <% for @m in @messages %>
  <h1>i</h1>
 <% end %>
</script>
```

What I need it to do is go hand-in-hand with Ruby. Don't know if this is possible.

Comment: HTML doesn't "run", it's not "code", it's just markup. The browser interprets it. Keep that in mind. JavaScript is actually executed.

Comment: The `<script>` tag introduces Javascript, not Ruby. It's unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @tadman Good point. I updated the title.

Comment: @GregHewgill I need the Ruby to run inside the JavaScript tag. I know it's probably more complicated than that, but can I hide it within the HTML?

Comment: Important information that should have been in your original question.

Comment: @Andy Good thing it is now.

Answer (score 2):

You would accomplish this by embedding a `script` element inside the body, and calling `document.write`

```
<p>
   Some generated HTML coming up....
</p>
<script>
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         document.write("<h1>" + i + "</h1>");
     }
</script>
<p>
   This will appear after the generated HTML
</p>
```

Comment: Will this flow with running a Ruby for loop?

Comment: @Collin - This is javascript running in a browser. It has nothing to do with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
var cars = ["car", "car", "car"];

for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = i;
  document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

This assumes you want to append the elements inside the `<body>`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zh0wc0zL/2/

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to create new DOM nodes directly in JS, and yes, you can do that. You can actually use HTML to do it, and it'll get parsed into the nodes you need.

If you need to do it as the page is loading, this will put nodes at the position in the `body` where the script was placed:

```html
<script>
  var cars = ["Honda", "Toyota", "Volkswagen"];
  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    document.write(`<h1>${i}: ${cars[i]}</h1>`);
  }
</script>
```

***Be aware*** that `document.write` is rarely used, and it only works *while the page is loading*. Beginners get stuck on this frequently.

---

If this needed to be done sometime after the page has loaded, you'd do it differently.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("button");

myButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var cars = ["Honda", "Toyota", "Volkswagen"];

  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<h1>${i}: ${cars[i]}</h1>`);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button">CLICK ME</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

This assumes there's an element on the page with the ID `"button"` and on with the ID `"container"` that should get the new elements.

Comment: Although I have done it before, I can't use JavaScript to create the values because there is also some Ruby involved.

Comment: @Collin: I'm not sure how that relates to your question.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this.
HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1 id = 'example'></hi>
</body
```

Javascript:
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML('whatever text you want');